# if statement comparing strings in java android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

I'm trying to write a method in az DBOpenHelper extends SQLOpenHelper class.
It supposed to evaluate if there's an entry in the DB with the same name.

```
public boolean existsContact(Contact contact) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String cname = contact.getName();
            if (name == cname) {

                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return true;
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();

    return false;
}
```

Here's the relevant part of Contact class:

```
 public class Contact {

    String _name;
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }
    }
```

Now here's the strange thing:

Scenario A : `if (name == cname)` where `name = "foo"` and `cname = "foo"`  equals false.
              Eclipse debugger show name's foo and cname's foo have different id's.
              both variables filled as seen before in code.

Scenario B: `if(name == cname)` where variabales are loaded like this:

```
String name = "foo";
String cname = "foo";
         statement equals true as it's supposed to.
```

Scenario C: `if("foo" == "foo")` equals true...BUT...debugger goes out the window. LogCat show debugger connected, but there's no activity in eclipse's Debug perspective. Breakpoints have no effect. No Threads shown.

Comment: better you use name.equals(cname); Don't ever use == for string comparison.

Comment: you can change code to check if name exists using sql and avoid looping data Ex: `SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + ' Where name = ' + contact.getName()`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In java, when using `==` on two objects, you're not actually comparing the strings themselves. You'll need to use `.equals(String)`.

`==` actually compares the two object's references, not their values.

`string1.equals(String target)` compares the two strings based off of the actual characters in the strings.

See: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 8):

**== operator check object reference are equal or not  but equals() method check values are same or not**

```
    if (name == cname) 
   {    
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return true;
  }
```

**change with it**

```
 if (name.equals(cname)){        
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When comparing objects in java that are not primitive data types (`int, char, boolean, etc...`), you have to use the method `Object#equals(Object)`, which returns a boolean.

So, when you are comparing two Strings, you are actually checking if the two Objects are the same instance, instead of the actual value.

All you have to do is just change `name == cname` to `name.equals(cname)`.