# Android Java Method not Calculating Correctly

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I'm making a small Pizza Order App for a college assignment. In the app, if the user selects "small" or "medium" or "large" from a radiobutton group, the price shown will be recalculated with the information given. However, for some reason, the price shown after each time is not correct.

Here's the relevant code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void Init(){
        onCalculate();

        switchToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (switchToggle.isChecked()){
                    switchToggle.setText("Yes");
                }
                else {
                    switchToggle.setText("No");
                }
            }
        });

        smallRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                sizeStatus = "Small";
                onCalculate();
            }
        });
        mediumRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                sizeStatus = "Medium";
                onCalculate();
            }
        });
        largeRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                sizeStatus = "Large";
                onCalculate();
            }
        });
        meatCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                onCalculate();
            }
        });
        cheeseCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                onCalculate();
            }
        });
        veggiesCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                onCalculate();
            }
        });

    }


    private void onCalculate(){
        resultTextView.setText("$" + Integer.toString(Order.CalculatePrice(sizeStatus, meatCheckBox.isChecked(), cheeseCheckBox.isChecked(), veggiesCheckBox.isChecked())));
    }
```

**Order.java**

```
public final class Order {

    public static int CalculatePrice(String size, boolean meat, boolean cheese, boolean veggies){
        int price = 0;

        if (size == "Small"){
            price += 9;
        }
        else if (size == "Medium"){
            price += 10;
        }
        else if (size == "Large"){
            price += 11;
        }
        if (meat == true){
            price += 2;
        }
        if (cheese == true){
            price += 2;
        }
        if (veggies == true){
            price += 2;
        }

        return price;
    }

}
```

Note that the Init() method is called in the onCreate() method in MainActivity.java.

sizeStatus is a variable declared in MainActivity and is set to "Small" (string) as default (same as the initial RadioButton check).

It starts up the app with the correct value of $9 since, that is the radiobutton defaulted as checked. After that it displays incorrect size values for each button randomly:

**Before Selection:**

http://prntscr.com/l6ke08

**After Selection:**

http://prntscr.com/l6ke6h

The rest of the method that handles toppings added to the pizza works fine. But the radiobuttons are messing up.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `==` is not the way to compare strings.

Comment: @user3923150 Do mark the answer as correct, it helps the future stack overflow readers and I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first look the thing that I think gets wrong is the `equals()` method not being used to compare the strings in your `calculatePrice()` method.

You should use a code like this:

```java
public final class Order {

    public static int CalculatePrice(String size, boolean meat, boolean cheese, boolean veggies){
        int price = 0;

        if (size.equals("Small")){
            price += 9;
        }
        else if (size.equals("Medium")){
            price += 10;
        }
        else if (size.equals("Large")){
            price += 11;
        }
        if (meat == true){
            price += 2;
        }
        if (cheese == true){
            price += 2;
        }
        if (veggies == true){
            price += 2;
        }

        return price;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

compare strings using:"string1.equals(String target)"
check below link:
[if statement comparing strings in java android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944799/if-statement-comparing-strings-in-java-android)

Answer (score 0):

`SetOnCheckedChangedListener` calls the function when checked status is changed. So, `onCheckedChanged` function is called, even if the radio button is UNCHECKED.

So, if you want to change savedStatus, you could use `isChecked` parameters, or try this.

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                case R.id.small_radio_button:
                    sizeStatus = "Small";
                    break;
                case R.id.medium_radio_button:
                    sizeStatus = "Medium";
                    break;
                case R.id.large_radio_button:
                    sizeStatus = "Large";
            }
            onCalculate();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Equals method for comparing `String` and use `equalsIgnoreCase` method for case complexity.

```
public static int CalculatePrice(String size, boolean meat, boolean cheese, boolean veggies){
    int price = 0;

    if (size.equalsIgnoreCase("Small")){ 
      price += 9;
    }
    else if (size.equalsIgnoreCase("Medium")){
      price += 10;
    }
    else if (size.equalsIgnoreCase("Large")){
      price += 11;
    }
    if (meat){
      price += 2;
    }
    if (cheese){
      price += 2;
    }
    if (veggies){
      price += 2;
    }

    return price;
  }
```